# php sort images by date

Tags: javascript, php

I am using this script to show all images in a directory and to display image size, etc. I've been trying different ways (and yes, I also used Google) to **sort them by date** but none worked for me.

```
<?php
    $dir = 'uploads/';
    $files = glob("$dir*.*");
    for($i=count($files)-1; $i >= 0; $i--):
        $image = $files[$i];
        $size = getimagesize($image);
        $image_height = $size[0];
        $file_size_byte = filesize($image);
        $file_size_kilobyte = ($file_size_byte/1024);
        $file_size_kilobyte_rounded = round($file_size_kilobyte,1);

    ?>

        <div class="fileDiv" onclick="showImage('<?php echo $image; ?>','<?php echo $image_height; ?>');">
            <div class="imgDiv"><img class="fileImg lazy" data-original="<?php echo $image; ?>"></div>
            <p class="fileDescription"><?php echo $image; ?></p>
            <p class="fileTime"><?php echo date ("F d Y H:i", filemtime($image)); ?></p>
            <p class="fileTime"><?php echo $file_size_kilobyte_rounded; ?> KB</p>
        </div>

    <?php endfor; 

?>
```

How do I have to modify this script to **sort the files by date and the last modified image to be displayed on top**? Could someone please help me how to do this? *Thanks* so much!

Comment: @cmorrissey My images arent't in an array ...

Comment: yes they are its `$files`

Comment: @cmorrissey I agree. But how to use glob here? I'm used to mysql database connections but doing things like this is quite new for me..

Comment: your using `glob` ... `$files = glob("$dir*.*");`

Comment: @cmor ok great thanks sorry didn't know how to search it in google

Comment: otherwise google for "bubble sort"... If nothing else helped you... its the "easiest" sort algorithm